# How to count two column values

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I want count two columns using power bi to create a visual.my measure as below

Test Measure = COUNTA('Export'[Line])+COUNTA('Export'[Line 2]),

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a calculated table with all the lines values, like this

```
TableValues =
DISTINCT ( UNION ( DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Line] ), DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Line_2] ) ) )
```

With that table done, you can write the following measure

```
CountValues =
VAR _CurrentValue =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( TableValues[Line] )
VAR _C1 =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( 'Table'[Line] ), 'Table'[Line] = _CurrentValue )
VAR _C2 =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( 'Table'[Line_2] ), 'Table'[Line_2] = _CurrentValue )
RETURN
    _C1 + _C2
```

The calculations count all the instances of a specific `Line`. It's important that the `TableValues` doesn't have any relationship with the other tables.

## Output

Using 'TableValues'[Line] as the `Line` and `CountValues` as the metric.

[image]

Comment: this works fine.How can we add another value column next to countvalues in matrix visual  if there any fail(column I in excel screen shot).I want capture no of done audits and no of fail audit for each line.